# Would Harry Potter have been a Master of Death?

Tags: harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-2

Harry Potter had the Elder Wand, Resurrection Stone, and Invisibility Cloak. If he hadn't broken the wand and left the stone in the Forbidden Forest, would he have become a Master of Death?

Comment: I thought this had been asked before over on SciFi.SE, but [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4610/76048) is the closest I can find.

Comment: Well, what *is* a "Master of Death" anyway? It's not entirely clear what that means and certainly isn't elaborated in the films at all. If anything, it's a fuzzy metaphor for...being able to trick death in whatever way using...precisely the 3 Deathly Hallows items. So yes, if he hadn't destroyed these items he would...still have them. Anything beyond that requires some clarification on what exactly you're looking for here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, he wouldn't. After all the story about being "Master of Death" is just that: A story, better said a fairy tale within the Potterverse.

Death has never been involved in making these magical items. It has been the Peverell brothers as can be read in HP and the Deathly Hallows (emphasis of mine):

> So it's true? asked Harry. "All of it? The Peverell brothers---"
>
> "---were the three brothers of the tale," said Dumbledore, nodding. "Oh yes, I think so. Whether they met Death on a lonely road . . . I think it more likely that the Peverell brothers were simply gifted, dangerous wizards who succeeded in creating those powerful objects. **The story of them being Death's own Hallows seems to me the sort of legend that might have sprung up around such creations**."
>
> <sub>* HP and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 'King's Cross station'</sub>

That said: No death involved means no master of death...

Comment: Argumentatively setting aside the semantics of what the term means, the term 'master of death' is still about the ABILITY to "cheat death". Even if death doesn't exist as a real life personification or entity, people (and wizards/witches) do in fact die! And we know there are entities that literally suck the goodness out of one's soul and can be fatal: Dementors.